# Transform value of all keys in dict with value matching condition

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dict like below

```
{'a': [{'id': 0, 'res': [0, 1]}, {'id': 1, 'res': [8, 9]}], 'b': [{'id': 26, 'f': ('f3', {'nrP': 1})}, {'if': 0, 'f': ('f1', {'init': 6, 'nrS': 14})}], 'c': ('setup', {}), 'd': ('setup', {'max': 'one', 'sim': 'true'}), 'e': [{'id': 8, 'period': ('sl160', 8), 'res': 23}], 'f': [2, 3], 'g': {'f0': 0, 'p0': [{'id': 1, 'Value': -1}], 'ref': [{'id': 0, 'rs': ('abc', 0)}]}}
```

Need to have all key's (including the nested ones) whose value is 1) for which the value is a tuple & 2) has exactly 2 elements in tuple and 3) both the elements are either strings or numbers (not dict/list or other data structure) converted to a string `tuple[0] + ":" + tuple[1]`.

Examples keys that would match the data above would be - `'period': ('sl160', 8)` & `'rs': ('abc', 0)`

For the above example the expected result would be as below.

```
{'a': [{'id': 0, 'res': [0, 1]}, {'id': 1, 'res': [8, 9]}], 'b': [{'id': 26, 'f': ('f3', {'nrP': 1})}, {'if': 0, 'f': ('f1', {'init': 6, 'nrS': 14})}], 'c': ('setup', {}), 'd': ('setup', {'max': 'one', 'sim': 'true'}), 'e': [{'id': 8, 'period': 'sl160 : 8', 'res': 23}], 'f': [2, 3], 'g': {'f0': 0, 'p0': [{'id': 1, 'Value': -1}], 'ref': [{'id': 0, 'rs': 'abc : 0'} ]}}
```

The conversion of the tuple to the string is fairly ok. I need to identify nested keys matching the condition above and do the transformation in place.

Comment: In general, when you need to process arbitrary nested structures you do it with a recursive function.

Comment: So you loop over all the elements of the dictionary. If the value is another dictionary, call the function recurively. Otherwise, check if it matches the conditions and replace the value.

Comment: @Barmar - see below - suggest improvements if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works

```
def convertTwoElmStrTupleToStr(dictIe):
    if isinstance(dictIe, dict):
        # base case
        for k, v in dictIe.items():
            if isinstance(v, tuple) and len(v) == 2 and (isinstance(v[0], str) or isinstance(v[0], int)) and (isinstance(v[1], str) or isinstance(v[1], int)):
                dictIe[k] = f'{v[0]} : {v[1]}'
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for item in v:
                    if isinstance(item, dict):
                       # call base case on each dict
                        convertTwoElmStrTupleToStr(item)
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                     # call base case on each dict
                    convertTwoElmStrTupleToStr(v)

    return dictIe
```

Output

```
>>> convertTwoElmStrTupleToStr(a)
{'a': [{'id': 0, 'res': [0, 1]}, {'id': 1, 'res': [8, 9]}], 'b': [{'id': 26, 'f': ('f3', {'nrP': 1})}, {'if': 0, 'f': ('f1', {'init': 6, 'nrS': 14})}], 'c': ('setup', {}), 'd': ('setup', {'max': 'one', 'sim': 'true'}), 'e': [{'id': 8, 'period': 'sl160 : 8', 'res': 23}], 'f': [2, 3], 'g': {'f0': 0, 'p0': [{'id': 1, 'Value': -1}], 'ref': [{'id': 0, 'rs': 'abc : 0'}]}}
```